# kafka allows addition of partitions to a topic but not deletion?

Tags: hash, apache-kafka, partitioning

Why does apache kafka allow only additions but not deletions of partitions in topics. How does it work internally . Does it use hashing for partitions ?

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning is indeed performed by hashing the message key with the murmur2 hash algorithm and then calculating this modulo *number of partitions*.
This is done at write time by the producer sending the message to the broker, who then stores it in the log for that partition. If there is no key in the message then the producer does round-robin.
All of this is the default behavior, the partitioner is pluggable, so you could do anything you want for this.

This is also the reason why you cannot remove partitions in Kafka, as this would mean that data would need to be re-partitioned and then distributed to the other partitions, which has several issues:

- the brokers don't how the producer selected the partition when the message was written
- the messages are old by now and would need to be inserted at earlier spots in the broker's log, which is not possible due to Kafka's linearly rising offsets

Adding partitions by contrast is fairly simple, as this only affects new messages. Basically, when you add partitions the producers will after some time (metadata refresh when metadata.max.age.ms is reached) notice new partitions and simply include these in its partitioning scheme, whatever it may look like.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Kafka does not support reduction of partitions of a topic as this would result in data loss. Furthermore, this would also cause more issues with keyed messages that have been distributed to particular partitions.

Coming to your question about hashing, by default, Kafka makes use of the [`DefaultPartitioner`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/717c55be971df862c55f55d245b9997f1d6f998c/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/DefaultPartitioner.java) (`org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner`) in order to distribute messages across topic partitions:

```
/**
 * Compute the partition for the given record.
 *
 * @param topic The topic name
 * @param key The key to partition on (or null if no key)
 * @param keyBytes serialized key to partition on (or null if no key)
 * @param value The value to partition on or null
 * @param valueBytes serialized value to partition on or null
 * @param cluster The current cluster metadata
 */
public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes, Cluster cluster) {
    if (keyBytes == null) {
        return stickyPartitionCache.partition(topic, cluster);
    } 
    List<PartitionInfo> partitions = cluster.partitionsForTopic(topic);
    int numPartitions = partitions.size();
    // hash the keyBytes to choose a partition
    return Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(keyBytes)) % numPartitions;
}
```

Essentially, the `DefaultPartitioner` makes use of *MurmurHash*, a non-cryptographic hash function which is usually used for hash-based lookup. This hash is then used in a modulo operation (`% numPartitions`) in order to ensure that the returned partition is within the range `[0, N]` where `N` is the number of partitions of the topic.

**Workaround**

Assuming that you still want to decrease the number of partitions of a topic, you can still create a new one with less partitions and then replicate the messages from the older topic to the newly created one. In this way, you will be able to distribute keyed messages to the correct partitions.